# Pitest: How to redirect the log output to a file?

Tags: console, pipe, pitest

I apply Pitest (PIT) using Maven to Java projects to conduct a mutation analysis. The console's pipe operator only catches Maven-related output but not output by PIT. (This happens both on Linux and Windows.)

How can I redirect the logging output shown on the console to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven output are going to `stdout` while some PIT logs are going to `stderr`. You need to also redirect `stderr` to get all logs.

```
# this will write both outputs to a file
mvn clean install &> both-outputs.log

# this will also write both outputs to a file
mvn clean install > both-outputs.log 2>&1

# to pipe both outputs you need to do this
mvn clean install 2>&1 | any-command-reading-from-stdin
```